# How select subobjects with condition using Core data?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

[Database stucture image.](https://habrastorage.org/storage2/e12/150/cff/e12150cff4f22e553436ecf1553992e8.png)[image: Database stucture image.]

Get `country` with predicate `active = 1` in debuger watch condition `where zactive = 1` it's ok.
In next view controller get sub-objects `country.regions` but request in debuger got only relationships condition. How send there `active = 1` condition for sub-objects? And same way for `region.items`.

Got some ideas:

1. Filter result from `country.regions` but query will remain the same
2. Build relationships myself

Answer (score 1):

You can create a fetch request with a predicate, and you can use the country object in your predicate.  Example:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Region"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
    @"country = %@ AND active = 1", country];
NSError *error;
NSArray *activeRegions = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request
    error:&error];
```

Comment: Thank you. This way like my idea "2) Build relationships himself". No any other way?

Comment: Test shows what after second request got cache error: "ERROR: The persistent cache of section information does not match the current configuration"

Comment: Problem with cache solved by using unical cache_id for each predicate.